# Hide rows with corresponding column empty

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google sheet and want to hide some rows having column F corresponding cell as empty.  Not sure how to do this. I read about *IF* and *QUERY*.
Any ideas on how to achieve this?
I was wondering if there were any online tools that could help to do this without writing any such function

Comment: Have you tried applying a filter to your data and just removing `Blanks` from the options? This way you don't need a formula, just apply a filter and remove `Blanks` from it.

Comment: Compared to the `FILTER` method (suggested by @LorenaGomez), which works in place, `QUERY` a range where the output of the function can be displayed.